# yield scrapy.Request does not invoke parse function on each iteration

Tags: python, scrapy

in my code i have to functions inside scrapy class.
start_request takes data from excel workbook and assigns value to `plate_num_xlsx` variable.

```
def start_requests(self):
    df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    columnA_values=df['PLATE']
    for row in columnA_values:
        global  plate_num_xlsx
        plate_num_xlsx=row
        print("+",plate_num_xlsx)
        base_url =f"https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num_xlsx}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
        url=base_url
        yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)
```

But, on each iteration it should invoke parse() method of Scrapy class and inside that function with each iterated newly value of `plate_num_xlsx` needs to compare the parsed value,
As I understood after print statements it first takes all values, assigns them then only with last value assigned calls parse() method. But for my crawler to function properly I need each time assigning happens to call and use that value inside def parse().
code is below;

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import pandas as pd

itemList=[]
class plateScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapePlate'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk']

    def start_requests(self):
        df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
        columnA_values=df['PLATE']
        for row in columnA_values:
            global  plate_num_xlsx
            plate_num_xlsx=row
            print("+",plate_num_xlsx)
            base_url =f"https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num_xlsx}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
            url=base_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        for row in response.css('div.resultsstrip'):
            plate = row.css('a::text').get()
            price = row.css('p::text').get()
            a = plate.replace(" ", "").strip()
            print(plate_num_xlsx,a,a == plate_num_xlsx)
            if plate_num_xlsx==plate.replace(" ","").strip():
                item= {"plate": plate.strip(), "price": price.strip()}
                itemList.append(item)
                yield  item
            else:
                item = {"plate": plate_num_xlsx, "price": "-"}
                itemList.append(item)
                yield item

        with pd.ExcelWriter('output_res.xlsx', mode='r+',if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
            df_output = pd.DataFrame(itemList)
            df_output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='result', index=False, header=True)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(plateScraper)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using global variables with scrapy in this manner will not work due to it's asynchronous runtime behavior.  What you can do alternatively is  pass the `plate_num_xlsx` variable as a callback keyword argument to the request object itself.

for example:

```
            plate_num_xlsx=row
            base_url =f"https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num_xlsx}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
            url=base_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs={'plate_num_xlsx': plate_num_xlsx})



    def parse(self, response, plate_num_xlsx=None):
        for row in response.css('div.resultsstrip'):
            plate = row.css('a::text').get()
            price = row.css('p::text').get()
            ...
```

Now the variable will be included as a parameter to the parse function.

Comment: Hey, what you have written is great! Thanks for it. Now, it works with different passed data values. But, it seems like in data.xlsx file it is in one format, but on output file it is reversed? Can it be that it parse from bottom to top? I dont think it would be so. But it parses strangely

Comment: Scrapy is asynchronous.  So there is no set order to which request get parsed first.  It's just whichever request finishes first @xlmaster

Comment: Great!! Thanks @Alexander you helped a lot with your answer

Comment: That means at least I can understand by count of data values in data.xlsx and output file if they are same then means start_request() has taken all values and passed to parse() function. But it result lesser value count in output value.

Comment: Look through your logs.  One of your requests could have timed out or an exception might have been raised while parsing a specific page. @xlmaster